req.body return empty object
i try to build a simple restapi, i still learning nodejs/expressjs here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2EqECiTBL8
the problem is when i try to post data like this:
.post((req, res) => {
        console.log('Received POST data:', req.body);
        res.json({
            "firstname": req.body.firstname,
            "lastname": req.body.lastname
        });
    })

the req.body is an empty object.
When i replaced req.body.lastname with data.employees[1] that worked fine.
Here is the code:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const data = {};
data.employees = require('../../data/employees.json');

router.route('/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        res.json(data.employees);
    })
    .post((req, res) => {
        res.json({
            "firstname": data.employees[0],
            "lastname": data.employees[1]
        });
    })

module.exports = router;

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.json());

// Routing
app.use('/', require('./routes/root'));
app.use('/subdir', require('./routes/subdir'));

// set up api or rest api
app.use('/employees', require('./routes/api/employees'));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running On Port ${PORT}`))

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Zaid",
        "lastname": "El khobzi"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "Jhon",
        "lastname": "Kennedy"
    }
]


How do you call/test your POST endpoint?

@pzaenger i use postman

That's good. But how does your actual request look like?

@pzaenger
POST /employees
Headers: {
'content-type': 'application/json',
'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.39.0',
accept: '/',
'postman-token': '4f654064-3153-4aa4-be6e-8ae6d12e2008',
host: 'localhost:3500',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'content-length': '0'
}
Content-Type: application/json
Received POST data: {}
